# Lazy load locales for nuxt-i18n

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

In nuxt-i18n you must specify the locales property with the locales your app will be supporting like this:

```
  locales: [
    {
      code: 'en',
      file: 'en-US.js'
    },
    {
      code: 'es',
      file: 'es-ES.js'
    },
    {
      code: 'fr',
      file: 'fr-FR.js'
    }
  ],
```

Could be this fetched from api endpoint and then fill the array?

I've seen something similar in this issue https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n/issues/256#issuecomment-505344965 but I have no idea how to run that code or even it's that possible.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple. Nuxt allows you to export an async function as options so I can get the data and next assign it to the i18n object.

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/configuration/#asynchronous-configuration

```
export default async () => {
  const data = await getCountries()

  const locales = []

  for (const locale of data) {
    locales.push({
      code: locale,
      file: `${locale}.json`
    })
  }

  return {
      build: {
          ...
      },
      env: {
          ...
      },
      modules: [
          'nuxt-i18n',
          ...
      ],
      i18n: {
          locales,
          strategy: 'prefix',
          detectBrowserLanguage: false,
          lazy: true,
          defaultLocale: 'es',
          langDir: 'translations/'
      },
      ...
  }
}
```